# How to sort pages in reverse chronological order?

Tags: sorting, kirby

I want to display pages in reverse chronological order based on page's name. Is there an easier way to do this than changing the page names?

Here is the Kirby's example.
    /content/blog/20121212-my-first-article
    /content/blog/20132206-a-second-article
    /content/blog/20142806-the-latest-article

I want the latest post – 20142806-the-latest-article – to be displayed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a kirby method named `flip`: `<?php $articles = $page->children()->flip() ?>`

https://getkirby.com/docs/cheatsheet/pages/flip

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For my knowledge I wonder if this can be set on the text file contained in the folder where lied the config.

Comment: I don't think so